# Sufficient mating material, less a king?

Tags: checkmate, material

As an extension to this question about [can a rook and knight *without a king* stalemate a opposing king](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/36874/can-whites-rook-and-knight-without-moving-white-king-force-stalemate), and the [traditional minimum-mating-material question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5028/what-is-sufficient-mating-material), I had a puzzle question:

What are the minimum combinations of material (without a king) required to forcibly mate an opposing king?

- R + R/Q is clearly sufficient
- R + N + N/B maybe, as an extension from the above stalemate question

On the other hand, there are some sets that fail without a king:

- B(w) + B(b) (but 3 bishops should work, so long as one is on a different color)

Comment: 3 bishops do not work to force a mate - the lone color bishop is not sufficient to force the king to a corner. Four bishops works though. Four knights, but not three (I think, after trying for a while). This would best be answered by an engine which can calculate without a King.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming opponent has no pieces:

1. 4 or more knights
2. 4 or more bishops, at least 2 per side
3. At least 2 pawns, but it also depends on where the pawns are
4. 2 or more major pieces
5. Queen and a minor piece
6. Rook and 2 minor pieces
7. 4 minor pieces
8. Pawn+Minor pieces/2 Minor Pieces(depending on where the pawn is or a major piece

If opponent have pieces:

1. Queen(maybe rook)+Minor Piece vs 1 pawn
2. Queen(maybe rook)+2 pawns vs Rook+Bishop+Pawn
3. Q+R vs Rook and bishop or 2 minor pieces(for most positions)

Comment: So it's 10 points or higher. Come to think of it, since K is ~4 points in strength, the traditional KBB/KBN is about 10 points. KR = 9 is exception.

Comment: @jf328 Yes, without pawns

Comment: In the 4 bishops case, you'll need at least *two* bishops from each colour, not one.

Comment: @jf328 Then maybe we could set K as 5 points, but then some pawnless endgames where a minor piece up is enough, or Qv 4minor piece

Comment: Note that KNN = 10 is also an exception.

Comment: @Glorfindel KBB*

Comment: No, I meant King + 2 Knights = 10 points, but not sufficient enough to enforce mate.

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh ok