# Is it possible to win with a black bishop and king vs a king?

Tags: bishop-endgame

I am playing with only a bishop (black squares) and king vs a lone king.
Is it possible for me to win?

Comment: Related question, but with a wider scope: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5028/what-is-sufficient-mating-material

Answer (score 1):

No. Even if you got your opponent's king to a corner and checked it with your bishop, your king can control only two of the three flight squares.

The most you could achieve is a stalemate, if your opponent helps. Therefore king and bishop vs king is considered a draw by insufficient material ("dead position" is the term used in the [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=208&view=article); see article 5.2.2).