# What is the longest non-cyclic forced sequence of moves?

Tags: problems, forced-move

I am looking for positions from where every move is forced up to a certain depth. If the original position (or one in between) occurs again, the sequence is finished there.

Comment: Do you mean that every move of both players is forced or of just one player? (In the first case, mates in N moves are out of the question, because the moves of the losing side are not forced as his decision makes no difference.)

Comment: Yes, it's about forced sequences for both players. It doesn't need to end in checkmate, the only requirement is that there is just one possible move for each player for a long time.

Comment: I think it eas not intended by the one asking the other question but it is trivial to construct a position that is forced to repeat again and again, making that sequence infinite.

Answer (score 5):

### 9 moves

In [the linked thread](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/4963/86) (not quite a duplicate), a valid [answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/4965/86) is posed to this question:

> You mean like this?

```
[Title "Vilhelm Röpke, Skakbladet 1942, Mate In 6"]
[FEN "K1k5/P1Pp4/1p1P4/8/p7/P2P4/8/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

> White mates in 6.

> I guess that's 9 consecutive forced moves. It would be eleven except for black's choice of promotion piece on his fifth move. I don't know if it's a record, and I don't know who composed this classic chess problem.

Comment: I miss understood what the OP was asking, I end up deleting my answer and upvoting yours since it goes straight to the point.

Comment: Can c1=Q be considered forced? I mean surely I had C1=N, C1=B, C1=R

Comment: @Alan It's not counted in the 9 half-moves for that reason. ("It would be eleven except for black's choice of promotion...").